# self.view.frame.size.height returns 0.0000 despite its explicit definition in updateViewContraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So. I'm trying to load an activity view load within a view's center. I have programmatically laid out my interface using updateViewConstraints. The view's height is set to 200 px like so:

```
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[postThumbnail(200)]|"
                                                                                 options:0
                                                                                 metrics:0
                                                                                   views:views]];
```

I do a standard sort of lazy load to get that view to appear. Problem is, when I try to define my activity indicator's center, I end up getting the coordinates (0,0) on my view. I feel as if I have fallen into a common trap.

I already have simply defined the activity indicator's center as (self.view.frame.size.width/2, 100) but I want to know why I can't use the frame.

In attempting to look into the issue myself, I tried NSLog(@"%f", self.postThumbnail.frame.size.height) at various points and kept getting the same value: 0.0000. It's probably also worth adding that the view takes up the defined amount of space (200 px) despite this odd log.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Did you try calling [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded] before you try your log?

Comment: I did, nothing changed. It's bizarre. Thanks for the advice, though.